# Addition of list elements without using sum method

Tags: list, input, sum

Create an integer list with the user given elements. Write a program to find the sum of the elements of the given input list without using the method sum(), and print result.

I know about the sum method but another way I don't know.

Comment: You'll need to use a for loop that loops over each element in your list and adds that value onto a variable that was initialised to zero outside the loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with For Loop . In c# for example ;

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 4, 13, 21, 6, 5 };

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum in numbers array :" + sum.ToString());
    }
}
```

**The Output : Sum in numbers array :49**